# Do you always add an apostrophe when adding an s to a first name?

Tags: punctuation

There are a few different ways I want to add an 'S' to the end of a first name.

Here are a few examples...

> This is my friend **Harrys** house.
>
> I picked **Harrys** hat up from the floor.
>
> I directed **Harrys** attention to the pool.

Should all of these examples have an apostrophe?

Comment: Those 3 examples should all have an apostrophe, as they are all possessives.  They refer to the house, hat and attention belonging to harry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

`Harry's` is the correct way to show that Harry owns something, wheter it's the house, the hat or even his attention.

To indicate possession in English, `'s` is attached to the end of the noun.  This is the case for all nouns, including names, except for certain plurals and the word `it`.

For plurals (and sometimes certain names, although this is debated) that end in s, the typical method to indicate possession is to just add the apostrophe on the end as in:

> Mothers' Day

For the word `it` possession does not use the apostrophe at all so you get: `its`.